# Removing <tr> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i remove entire `<tr>` from a table using javascript without using `getElementByID` because i do not have any IDs of table `tr` or `tds`

Comment: Could you read that sentence back and reword it so it makes sense? Also, it'd be handy if you could post the code you have tried. We're not here to do your work for you!

Comment: yes Alex im also not even hiring you for my work, i have done my part and requested people, if u know about this your suggestion are highly appreciable otherwise i have not called you here

Comment: You've given us no context to work with! I had to read through to the bottom to realise that some click event was what's triggering this. Please try to give AS MUCH detail as possible in your question. We're not mind readers

Answer (score 4):

Assume your table has id="mytable":

This is how you get all the trs:

```
1. var trs = document.getElementById("mytable").rows; or
2. var trs = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Now do this:

```
while(trs.length>0) trs[0].parentNode.removeChild(trs[0]);
```

If you don't have id for your table and you have only one table on the page, do this:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
```

It would be hard to remove a specific tr if you don't give it an id. If you want to remove certain kind of trs, give them a class attribute and remove only those trs with this class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('tr, td').remove();
});
```

Or if — for whatever reason — you'd like to remove all contents of a table:

```
$('table').empty();
```

Comment: thats for the reply but dont have to use jquery

Comment: AFIK .remove() removes all DOM elements in jQuery object, isn't it? If it is then .each() is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Once you have identified the `<tr>` you wish to remove (you haven't provided enough context to your question to suggest (without making lots of assumptions) how you might do that):

```
tr_element.parentNode.removeChild(tr_element)
```

Comment: i just have to remove a row and i dont have any ID of any row td or table, inshort user will press remove button it will remove entire row with having knowledge of ID

Comment: Then you need to capture the event target of the click, and loop through `element.parentNode` until you find a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        <html>
        <head>
          <style>
        </style>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <table>
         <tr>
          <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>
         </tr>
         </table>

        <button>Empty</button>
        <script>
          $("button").click(function () {
            $("table").empty();
          });
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```